# EWS CreateAttachment API call not working

Tags: php, curl, exchangewebservices

I'm currently facing some problems with the `CreateAttachment` API call in EWS 2010. We are using PHP `5.5` with curl `7.49.1`.

We are currently using the following little script to test this issue:

```
$ewswrapper = new EWSWrapper($host, $user, $pass);

try {

    // See examples:
    //
    // http://jamesarmes.com/php-ews/doc/0.1/examples/contact-set-update-photo.html
    // https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/blob/master/examples/contact/set-photo.php

    $picture = base64_decode(" ... some valid base64 image ... ");

    $attachment = new EWSType_FileAttachmentType();
    $attachment->IsContactPhoto = true;
    $attachment->Content = $picture;
    $attachment->Name = "ContactPicture.jpg";
    $attachment->ContentType = "image/png";

    // Create the attachment request
    $attRequest = new EWSType_CreateAttachmentType();
    $attRequest->ParentItemId = new EWSType_ItemIdType();
    $attRequest->ParentItemId->Id = " ... some ItemId of a contact ... ";
    $attRequest->ParentItemId->ChangeKey = " ... some ChangeKey of the contact ... ";
    $attRequest->Attachments = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfAttachmentsType();
    $attRequest->Attachments->FileAttachment = [];
    $attRequest->Attachments->FileAttachment[] = $attachment;

    $ewswrapper->service->CreateAttachment($attRequest);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

The returned status code of the response is `100`. As far as we can tell, the response is empty. Dumping the request before sending it shows us a valid xml output that should theoretically work. We have checked both the official Microsoft documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa565931(v=exchg.140).aspx and the API examples at http://jamesarmes.com/php-ews/doc/0.1/examples/contact-set-update-photo.html.

Other requests to the API work perfectly. We can create, update, query and delete just fine, it seems to be this request specifically which fails.

We would highly appreciate any pointers into the right direction! Thanks in advance! If more information is needed regarding the code, infrastructure, etc, please ask!